# Convert string to numbers

Tags: javascript

I have multiple strings that looks like these:
550 e, 1,550 e, 1.550,00 e
I need to convert it to numbers so I can compare its values.

I removed currency part (e) w/ `split()` and then `join()` but how to get numbers from that?

Comment: So, if you returned it wth the join, you would have a string of *550*. *1.550,00* etc, correct?

Comment: If the `,` is meant to be a decimal point, change it to `.`, while replacing other `.`s with the empty string, then pass to `Number`

Comment: `var number = parseInt("1550 e")` out: 1550

Comment: @Fallenreaper, correct

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like :

```
var integer = parseInt(yourString, 10);
```

for decimal numbers :

```
 var decimal= parseFloat(yourString);
```

Answer (score -1):

use `Regular Expression` to capture digits followed by optional decimal.

```js
var regex = /\d+.?\d+/g;

const arrofStrings = ["550 e", "1,550 e", "1.550,00 e"];

const numbers = arrofStrings.map((str) => {
    str = str.replace(',', '');
    return Number(str.match(regex));
});

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: almost, note that 1,550 and 1.550,00 are same, they both should be, for example, 1550,00

Comment: When running this code base, 1.550,00 should return 1550, not 1.55, so you would need to account for that

Comment: I solved this with: `arrofStrings.map( item => parseInt(item.split(" ")[0].replace(".","").split(",")[0]) )`, though this is resolving for ints only, and not accounting for floats.